# Google Play Developer API with PHP

Tags: php, authorization, google-play-developer-api, login-required

I want to protect and verify in-app purchases against counterfeit transactions using PHP with the Google Play Developer API. I have reviewed Google Docs for this. I first created an access_token by completing the steps in this link https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization. Then i tried performing the actions described in this link https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get#auth, but I failed. My code and the result I get is the following.

My codes:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'access_token: my_access_token',
    'expires_in: 3600',
    'token_type: Bearer'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/my.package.name/purchases/products/myProductId/tokens/myPurchaseToken");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result=curl_exec($curl); 
echo $result;
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

The result:

```
{
error: {
errors: [
{
domain: "global",
reason: "required",
message: "Login Required",
locationType: "header",
location: "Authorization"
}
],
code: 401,
message: "Login Required"
}
}
```

Where am I doing wrong, what should I do? Thank you from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not give header like that with bearer type tokens. Your code should be like:

```
    <?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer your_access_token";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization )); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/my.package.name/purchases/products/myProductId/tokens/myPurchaseToken");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $result=curl_exec($curl); 
    echo $result;
    curl_close($curl);
    ?>
```